# DB2 Usage of views in triggers

Tags: triggers, db2

in have some triggers implemented and in this I am accessing a view which is a bit complex.
I have the feeling that the view is generated each time new when I am entering the trigger which takes a quite long.
Is it possible to build a view for a specific input parameter or what will be the best solution here?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG
 NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON DD
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEWITEM
 FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
 WHEN(SELECT 1 FROM MYVIEW WHERE ID = NEWITEM.ID)
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE 123 ('Not allowed')
```

Comment: There is no such meaning as "view is generated each time". The corresponding SELECT statement defined for this view is executed every time. What you can do is to materialize the result of this query once (`INSERT INTO MYTAB (ID, ...) SELECT ID, ... FROM MYVIEW`) and use this "pseudo-mqt" in your trigger. Note, that the table contents won't change upon changes in the base tables of this view, unless you are able to create MQT with REFRESH IMMEDIATE instead of your view and this "pseudo-mqt". [CREATE TABLE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-table).

Comment: Does the MQT table refresh automatically on any update, insert or delete ofthe source tables and can I add an index on them?

Comment: MQTs defined as REFRESH IMMEDIATE are updated automatically. The query must meet quite restrictive requirements to be used in MQT of this type. REFRESH DEFERRED MQTs are not updated automatically, you need to run REFRESH TABLE manually to fully update it with current result of the query. You may create non-unique indexes on both types of MQTs.

Comment: Due to performance, when I am inserting an new item in this table, is the MQT table updated immediateley, means will I have a longer lasting insert until the MQT table is updated?

Comment: Sure, the data change statements on base tables will have some penalty because of presence of REFRESH IMMEDIATE MQT.

Comment: Is it also possible to define a session wide table, this means when I am inserting via JPA, I want to create a temporary table which is only valid in the session, and be deleted after the last trigger was executed?

Comment: You can't reference Declared Globsl Temporery Table in a trigger, but you may reference Created GTT. This CGTT will exist in every session and be empty initially.

Comment: Do you have an example with CGTT?

Comment: [CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-global-temporary-table)

Comment: Can I say that a trigger inherit another trigger, because I want to create such a CGTT once and in a trigger we cannot say which trigger is fired first. Or how can I realize this?

Comment: There is no such meaning as "trigger inheritance". If you have multiple triggers on the same operation, then they fire in the ordrer of their creation time. Chech the `syscat.triggers` system view on this.

Comment: What is exactly the difference between by system maintained and user maintained mqts, I do not understand fully.

Comment: You may update user maintained MQTs manually as other ordinary tables. System maintained MQTs are updated either automatically or with the `REFRESH TABLE` statement only.